OTEL Collector unable to connect to Jaeger when both are running as docker containers
Docker Command to run jaeger
docker run --rm --name jaeger -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true -p 16686:16686 -p 5000:4317 jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest

Docker Command to run Otel Collector
docker run --rm --name otelcollector --env COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true -p 127.0.0.1:4317:4317 -p 127.0.0.1:55679:55679 -v "C:\OpenTelemetryCollector\otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otelcol/config.yaml" otel/opentelemetry-collector --config=/etc/otelcol/config.yaml

The otel-collector-config.yaml has the following configuration
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"  # Listening on all IP addresses, port 4317 for gRPC
      http:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4318"  # Listening on all IP addresses, port 4318 for HTTP/JSON

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  logging:
    verbosity: detailed
  otlp:
    endpoint: "localhost:5000"  # Assuming Jaeger collector is accessible at this endpoint
    tls:
      insecure: true  # Use 'false' and configure TLS settings for secure connection

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, otlp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]

In my web api i have the trace metrics support using the following code
            traceProviderBuilder.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
            {
                options.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317");
            });

Whenever I execute an endpoint, i am getting the error in otelcolletor container. Error is
2024-05-16T12:06:58.501Z        info    exporterhelper/retry_sender.go:118      Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "otlp", "error": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused\"", "interval": "21.931525309s"}
2024-05-16T12:07:13.343Z        error   exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101      Exporting failed. Dropping data.       {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "otlp", "error": "no more retries left: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused\"", "dropped_items": 6}
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.newQueueSender.func1
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.100.0/exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*boundedMemoryQueue[...]).Consume
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.100.0/internal/queue/bounded_memory_queue.go:52
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*Consumers[...]).Start.func1
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.100.0/internal/queue/consumers.go:43
2024-05-16T12:07:20.435Z        error   exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101      Exporting failed. Dropping data.       {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "otlp", "error": "no more retries left: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: connection refused\"", "dropped_items": 5}
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/exporterhelper.newQueueSender.func1
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.100.0/exporterhelper/queue_sender.go:101
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*boundedMemoryQueue[...]).Consume
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.100.0/internal/queue/bounded_memory_queue.go:52
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter/internal/queue.(*Consumers[...]).Start.func1
        go.opentelemetry.io/collector/exporter@v0.100.0/internal/queue/consumers.go:43

however if i change the url to http://localhost:5000 traces get posted to jaeger.
I have even tried to change the endpoint: "localhost:5000" to "jaeger:5000" in otel config file but to no avail.

Please check this issue: https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/issues/5737

In the scenario you're running here localhost as far as the collector is concerned, is itself, not your local machine.
Try changing the localhost:5000 in your collector config to docker.host.internal:5000 instead.
Alternatively, I'd recommend using a docker-compose file so they're in the same domain/dns boundary and you don't need to open up more ports on your machine.
